# como indexar um objeto numericamente em Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lógica

estou recebendo um .csv como este:

```
animal, branco
animal, preto
inseto, branco
inseto, preto
animal, cinza
```

quero poder usar essa massa de dados desta forma:

```
// obj = { animal : [branco, preto, cinza] , inseto:[branco, preto]}
```

MAS que eu consiga acessar essas informações com index numerico (algo como isso)

```
// obj[0] => animal : [branco, preto, cinza]
// obj[1] => inseto :[branco, preto]
// obj[0[2]] => cinza
// obj[1[0]] => branco
```

no momento estou usando um forEach assim:

```
const csvFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/in/classification.csv', 'utf8');
let data = csvFile.split('\n');
let final = {};
csv.forEach(function (row) {
    row = row.split(',');
    if (!final[row[0]]) {
        final[row[0]] = [];
    }
    final[row[0]].push(row[1]);
});

// output: { animal : [branco, preto, cinza] , inseto:[branco, preto]}
```

mas eu nao  consigo acessar as propriedades usando index numerico.
existe forma melhor de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para aceder com índice numérico deves usar arrays. E dentro da array podes ter objetos.

Algo assim:

```js
const csvFile = `
animal, branco
animal, preto
inseto, branco
inseto, preto
animal, cinza
`;
//const csvFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/in/classification.csv', 'utf8');

const data = csvFile.split('\n');
const types = {};
data.forEach(function(row) {
  if (!row.trim()) return; // empty line;
  const [type, value] = row.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
  if (!types[type]) {
    types[type] = [];
  }
  types[type].push(value);
});
const final = Object.keys(types).reduce((arr, type) => {
  return arr.concat(
    [type, types[type]]
  );
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(final));

// output: { animal : [branco, preto, cinza] , inseto:[branco, preto]}
```

Comment: sua resposta me ajudou muito mas o output que obtive foi este 
  // ["animal",["branco","preto","cinza"],"inseto",["branco","preto"]]
o que me impede de poder usar "cinza" como uma posição do array 'animal'

Comment: @FelipeG.Santos dá um exemplo de como usarias `final`. Na pergunta deste o exemplo `obj[0[2]] => cinza` e isso é o que  minha resposta faz. Mas dá um exemplo que posso adaptar a resposta.

Comment: o seu codigo funcionou bem pra mim, consigo acessar as posições numericamente, mas se eu printar final[1] a resposta que deveria ser 'inseto' é na verdade '['branco','preto','cinza']' , porque esse array nao está sendo valor para chave 'animal' e sim uma outra chave, se eu printar 'obj[0[2]]' vou ter apenas 'undefined' como output

Comment: @FelipeG.Santos `final[1][2]`, tens de usar `[]` seguidos e não uns dentro de outros